# key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "x": current value is "y"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I got 2 services "x" and "y". They were once deployed by the same helm chart together (2 kind deployment definitions in the same file, 2 kind service definitions etc.).

I have now separated the helm chart to 2 little ones, each for its respective service. I have no problem installing service "x", but when trying to helm install service "y" I get this error:

> invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "y": current value is "x"

My helm chart doesn't contain anything called `"meta.helm.sh/release-name"`. What can I do to fix it and install the service?